# Compare std::ostream to see if it is std::cout ("no match for 'operator=='")

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operators, ostream

The functionality of this function is that it will output(to terminal or file depending on the type of ostream& os object passed as a parameter to it) the MyString data (the C-string representation held within m_buffer). I am receiving a compiler error that states that "no match for 'operator=='", specifically in the part of the code that states "if(os == std::cout)" Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
//in header file
friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const MyString & myStr);

//in cpp file
bool MyString::operator==(const MyString & other)const{
if(strcmp(m_buffer,other.m_buffer) == 0){
    return true;
}else if (strcmp(m_buffer,other.m_buffer) != 0){
    return false;
}
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyString& myStr){
  if(os == std::cout){
  os << myStr.m_buffer << std::endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you want that logic? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Note:  std::cout is declared (in <iostream>) as one a basic_ostream objects.  Thus, by inheritance alone, std::cout is-a std::ostream.  The boolean test is un-necessary.

Answer (score 6):

You can compare the addresses:

```
if (&os == &std::cout) {
  os << myStr.m_buffer << std::endl;
}
```

> it will output(to terminal or file depending on the type of ostream& os object passed as a parameter to it)

`os` can also be a file stream since file streams also derived from `std::ostream`/`std::istream`. So writing to `os` will write to the terminal or file that the stream represents so there's really no need for the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `std::ostream` class aka `std::basic_ostream < char >` doesn't provide by any means comparison operators, and in general does not make sense to compare streams.

That said, a possible solution ( based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60961071/9009815) ) is this

```
if( std::addressof( os ) == std::addressof( std::cout ) )
  {
    os << myStr.m_buffer << std::endl;
  }
```

--

References:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof